# Execute function when a user has entered more than 5 characters in text box

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run a jQuery function when a user types in more than 5 characters in a text box. So far I've managed to get my script to run using the keyup function, however this causes the script to run the moment the user types in the very first character and I only want it to run when the user has typed in 5 or more characters.

Here's my code, I'm brand new to jquery so would really appreciate it if someone could please show me where I am going wrong with this. thanks in advance,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //alert('Document is ready');
        $('#search').keyup(function() {
            if ($("#search").val().length > 3)
                var sel_stud = $(this).val();
                //alert('You picked: ' + sel_stud);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "include/fetch_search.php",
                    data: 'theOption=' + sel_stud,
                    success: function(whatigot) {
                        //alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                        $('#search_results').html(whatigot);
                        $('#theButton').click(function() {
                        alert('You clicked the button');
                    });
                } //END success fn
            }); //END $.ajax
        })}; //END dropdown change event
    }); //END document.ready
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot the brackets and placed 3 instead of 5 ... I think the problem is just that

Comment: To add to the already mentioned solutions, if your user keeps typing your ajax call will trigger a lot of times. You should take that in consideration and only make an ajax call once every time interval (or keys pressed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You forgot to put the keys on the if statement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
//alert('Document is ready');

                $('#search').keyup(function ()  {
                    if($("#search").val().length > 5) {

                        var sel_stud = $(this).val();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "include/fetch_search.php",
                            data: 'theOption=' + sel_stud,
                            success: function(whatigot) {
    //alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                                $('#search_results').html(whatigot);
                                $('#theButton').click(function() {
                                    alert('You clicked the button');
                                });
                            } //END success fn
                        }); //END $.ajax
                    }
                })}; //END dropdown change event
            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
```

This is what you had:

```
if($("#search").val().length > 3)
```

That if statement won't do anything, you have to wrap some code inside it, that's what the code above does (and changed the 3 for a 5 :S).

Comment: thank you for your response, however I tried this and the script still did not execute :(

Comment: oh ok, managed to get it working, I had to remove one of the brackets from end dropdown change event. will accept once it lets me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to have checked in for 5 rather 3

```
        if ($("#search").val().length >=5)
```

And this line

```
       })}; //END dropdown change event
```

should be modified to this

```
       }); //you just added an extra } at the end
```

I guess rest is fine

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(function() {
            $('#search').keyup(function (e)  {    
            if($(this).val().length >= 5)
                alert('5th character entered');
            }) 
        }); //END document.ready
```

also remove extra ending curly-brace from code:

```
 }); //END dropdown change event
```

instead of

```
 })}; //END dropdown change event
```